# Unable to get SANE working on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, scanner, sane, hplip

I've tried to make my Raspberry Pi into a print/scan server today. The CUPS print server install & config ran fine and everything works, however I'm not able to get SANE scan server to work.

I'm using the hplip library from the raspbian repo

When running a scan program (eg. scanimage) it fails with an error

```
scanimage: open of device hpaio:/net/HP_Color_LaserJet_CM1312nfi_MFP?zc=NPI156760 failed: Error during device I/O
```

When examining the syslog, I found the following:

```
Jun 27 18:20:21 raspberrypi scanimage: scan/sane/soapht.c 90: 
  unable to load restricted library /usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_soapht.so:
  /usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_soapht.so:
  cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It looks like the required library is missing, however upon examining the directory:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ll /usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/
total 184
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    50 Jun 27 18:02 bb_marvell.so -> /usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_marvell-x86_32.so
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 34191 Jun 27 18:02 bb_marvell-x86_32.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    49 Jun 27 18:02 bb_soapht.so -> /usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_soapht-x86_32.so
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 53985 Jun 27 18:02 bb_soapht-x86_32.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    47 Jun 27 18:02 bb_soap.so -> /usr/share/hplip/scan/plugins/bb_soap-x86_32.so
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 17552 Jun 27 18:02 bb_soap-x86_32.so
-rw-r----- 1 root root 13019 Jun 27 18:08 hp-check.log
```

The file in question exists.

I tried reinstalling the hplip library from the website, instead of the repo, however I'm getting errors such as:

```
configure: error: "cannot find libjpeg support"
```

When trying to install all of the required dependencies as people suggested while troubleshooting this, I get a lot of missing packages:

```
E: Unable to locate package libcups2-dev
E: Unable to locate package libcupsimage2-dev
E: Package 'libdbus-1-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'ghostscript-x' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg8-dev
...
```

I spent the past few hours trying to fix this to no avail

EDIT: Also, when running hp-check, it displays a lot of missing packages (probably the ones missing above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scan plugin exists but isn't appropriate for a Raspberry Pi (which isn't *x86* but ARM). If HP don't provide an ARM-compatible plugin for your scanner then I'm afraid you won't be able to get it to work on your Pi...

Comment: Completely missed that, looks like I'll have to find a different use for the raspi. Thanks!